# jQuery .find() returning old version of child as well as updated

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the Chrome console, `$("#masthead").find("#fclass_id")` gives me the correct element:

```
[<input id=​"fclass_id" name=​"fclass_id" type=​"hidden" value=​"270">​]
```

But `$("#masthead").find("input")` gives a second, older version of the element:

```
[<input id=​"fclass_id" name=​"fclass_id" type=​"hidden" value=​"270">​,
 <input id=​"fclass_id" name=​"fclass_id" type=​"hidden" value=​"275">]
```

This second element is not in the dom currently. The field's `value` was 275 before it was overwritten by `$("#fclass_id").val("270");`

Any ideas on why the old version is being returned also?

Comment: That is because of duplicate id your id selector fetches only one (The first one in DOM with the duplicate id). but `input` selector fetches all of them. Inspect your html you should see both the inputs there.

Comment: *"This second element is not in the dom currently"* Are you sure? i find that hard to believe, given the results of `$("#masthead").find("input")`. Most likely you aren't removing it correctly (or, at all.)

Comment: What does `$("#masthead").find("input")` return before you overwrite the value?

Comment: I can't reproduce this now. I need to work shorter hours...upvoting everyone